# How to convert an Observable<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>> to Observable<HttpEvent<any>> in Angular AuthInterceptor service?

Tags: angular

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {        
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return this.usersService.authenticatedUser$.pipe(concatMap((user: LoggedInUsers) => {
            return this.usersService.validateUser(user).pipe(map((accessToken: AccessToken) => {
                return req.clone({
                    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', accessToken.token)
                })
            }));            
        })).pipe(map((req: HttpRequest<any>) => next.handle(req)));
    }
}
```

I tried to use `forkJoin` for feeding two observables, but `validateUser()` is depending on 1 argument that is, the authenticated user. So, need to use `concatMap()` so that I can wait for one observable to complete, but unable to return the desired `Observable` type.

Comment: format your code better please, like it is in my response for example.

Answer (score 0):

At first `concatMap` is not the best choice, usually for such a case it is better to use `switchMap`. And to open observable inside observable instead of `map` use `switchMap` again. You can also use multiple operators in `pipe` by chaining them together with a comma, instead of calling `.pipe()` again. Here is the working solution:

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.usersService.authenticatedUser$.pipe(
      switchMap((user: LoggedInUsers) => this.usersService.validateUser(user)),
      switchMap((accessToken: AccessToken) => {
        const request = req.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders().set(
            'Authorization',
             accessToken.token
          ),
        });
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: @Jineapple Thanks for your edit. I had tested previous version, it also worked, but yours looks really better.

Answer (score 0):

Since `next.handle` return an `Observable` you should use one of the [flattening operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) instead of a simple `map`.
You can think at the flattening operators as you think at the [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator, but they completes the inner `Observable`, allowing you to flat `Observable<Observable<T>>` into `Observable<T>`.
In this scenario the best suited operatir is [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), because

> On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed

You code would become:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {        
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return this.usersService.authenticatedUser$.pipe(concatMap((user: LoggedInUsers) => {
            return this.usersService.validateUser(user).pipe(map((accessToken: AccessToken) => {
                return req.clone({
                    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', accessToken.token)
                })
            }));            
        })).pipe(switchMap((req: HttpRequest<any>) => next.handle(req)));
    }
}
```

So the `Observable` returned by `next.handle` is completed inside `switchMap` and your type is flattened.

---

Remember that you can use several operators inside a single `pipe`. I would advise to do it since it really increase readibility. Your code could be like

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.usersService.authenticatedUser$.pipe(
      // would another flattening operator be better suited here?
      concatMap((user: LoggedInUsers) => {
        return this.usersService.validateUser(user);
      }),
      map((accessToken: AccessToken) => {
        return req.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', accessToken.token),
        });
      }),
      switchMap((req: HttpRequest<any>) => next.handle(req))
    );
  }
}
```